# How can I migrate Exchange 2007 public folders into SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, migration, exchange-server

We recently upgraded from Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010 by creating a new virtual machine and migrating all of the user mailboxes from the 2007 box to the 2010 box.

We're having a little trouble migrating all of the public folders and I was wondering if there's a free (or cheap) and safe method of migrating calendars and contact lists into SharePoint 2010 from Exchange 2007.

Something built into either Exchange or SharePoint would be best, I think, but I'm open to suggestions that involve third-party applications.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SP Server (not SP Foundation) and configured the Search Service application on your SP Farm, you might have a better (easier to implement with no cost of a third-party tool) option instead of migrating the content of the public folders into SP 2010.

Keep the content of public folders where they are.

Using the Search Service Application,

1. Create a new crawl rule to periodically crawl the content of the public folders.

   [image: New crawl rule]
2. Add a content source for exchange public folders

   [image]
   [image]

This option will enable you to integrate the content of the Exchange public folders with SP.

You can read more about performing this option on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806927.aspx)

Comment: This is a great bit of info (and might eventually get used) but right now I'm more focused on actually moving the items into SharePoint rather than just referencing them from the original location.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/moving-exchange-public-folders-to-sharepoint.aspx

http://www.quest.com/public-folder-migrator-for-sharepoint/

Comment: Have you used this product?  Can you give me an idea how much it costs?  Do you work for the people who make it?  Is this the only option for what I want to do?